# How to reference a class and method from a javascript library included on index.html

Tags: reactjs, tealium

I have a SPA built in React. I need to include a JavaScript library for analytics from a CDN -it should not be bundled with the rest of the JS libraries.

So far I've learned that it is not webpack's job and that I should use a script loader, like scriptjs. I found this thread but I can't understand the implementation: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/240.

I need to:

1. include the JS library from the CDN. So far I've done that by referencing it on the Index.html page. (ie `<script src="//path/to/cdn/utag.js"></script>`)
2. reference the library from components in the React app. There is a class `utag` with methods `view()` and `link()` that I need to call when buttons are pressed in the application. If I try utag.link() from within a method in a react component the object utag is not defined and react will not compile.

How can I include this library so it is accessible by all my components and how do i reference the class and methods that I need?

Thanks!

Comment: You did it right - just include it into your index.html. The rest depends on how utag library is exporting the class. If it just defines global variables, when you can access it with window.utag.

Answer (score 1):

The script reference in the HTML is fine.

For analytics, you might want to build a wrapper into your application that handles events and tests for the availability of the downstream functions, along the lines of:

```
var analytics = {
  view: function(a,b,c){
    if(window.utag && window.utag.view && typeof window.utag.view == "function"){
      window.utag.view(a,b,c);
    } else {
      // handle lack of Tealium availability here
    }
  },
  link: function(a,b,c){
    if(window.utag && window.utag.link && typeof window.utag.link == "function"){
      window.utag.link(a,b,c);
    } else {
      // handle lack of Tealium availability here
    }
  }
};
```

You can then use analytics.view() and analytics.link() immediately, and write code to handle Tealium not having been loaded (e.g. a one second delay followed by a follow-up attempt).